# Cancelable timeout in Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I want to implement a countdown timer using [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/github/ReactiveCocoa) in iOS. The timer should run for X seconds and do something in every second. The part I cannot figure out is the way I could **cancel the timeout**.

```
RACSubscribable *oneSecGenerator = [RACSubscribable interval:1.0];
RACDisposable *timer = [[oneSecGenerator take:5] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"Tick");
}];
```

Comment: Why not plain old `NSTimer`? You can `- invalidate` it...

Comment: I'm trying to make use of the reactive behavior. I know how to do it with NSTimer but this is an experiment to produce less error prone code. Imperative programming can hardly deal with the complexity of big state spaces. This is where reactive programming can help.

Comment: In the current version of ReactiveCocoa, the `take` operation will automatically terminate the `oneSecGenerator` Signal once it has taken the specified number of values.

Comment: Yes, this is how `take` always has worked. The question was how to prevent it from timing out. I listed a solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, I found the solution. The trick is to merge the cancel signal into the tick signal, then take X samples. The final subscribers will receive a *next* event every time the tick signal ticks and *completed* when the 'take' is finished. Cancellation can be implemented by sending error on the cancel timer.

```
__block RACSubject *cancelTimer = [RACSubject subject];
RACSubscribable *tickWithCancel = [[RACSubscribable interval:1.0] merge:cancelTimer];
RACSubscribable *timeoutFiveSec = [tickWithCancel take:5];

[timeoutFiveSec subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"Tick");
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
} completed:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed");
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}];
```

To activate cancel, one has to do the following.

```
[cancelTimer sendError:nil]; // nil or NSError
```

Comment: which version of ReactiveCocoa are you running? My version doesn't accept a parameter to ```RACSubscribable merge```.

Comment: I use Cocoa Pods and that is at ver 0.8. As I have seen in the new version RACSubscribable was renamed to RACSignal. This may be a difference for you. I use this overload `- (RACSubscribable *)merge:(RACSubscribable *)subscribable;`

Comment: I dont have the latest either; I grabbed mine from github. There're ```Cancellable``` subscribables, that's probably worth looking into. I need something similar to cancel a sequence of asynchronous network operations.

Comment: I think the `Cancellable` does something similar under the hood as we do here. I haven't gone into detail yet but it seems like they are instatiated by a `Subscribable` and a block. I suppose the block will have to implement the cancellation. I couldn't find examples for that.

Comment: It looks like ```Cancelable``` has a cancel method, which calls tearDown on the whole subscribable chain. But it didn't work as I would've expected. I think github might be a good place to ask, the authors/contributors react (heh) pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [TakeUntil operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229530%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which does [exactly what you want:](https://github.com/blog/1107-reactivecocoa-for-a-better-world) relays events from a stream until another one produces a value.

Comment: TakeUntil is not applicable in my case as it does not provide means to distinguish between the final cases. It is important whether the timeout happened or the cancel was fired. TakeUntil simply completes the stream when a next is sent on cancel. At least this is how it's implemented in Reactive Cocoa.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you have to error on cancellation. In that case, TakeUntil isn't for you indeed.